# Curve25519 function, scalar multiplikation

Tags: elliptic-curves

[This](https://cr.yp.to/ecdh/curve25519-20060209.pdf) is the main paper for Curve25519. In section 2: Specification there is a important theorem. In this theorem Bernstein defines the function $X_0 : E(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow F_{p^2}$.

**First Question**: Curve25519 is a Montgomery curve and uses the projektive arithmetic, which only needs the x-coordinate. The defined functions makes a scalarmultiplication and then takes the x-coordinate from the result. Therefore why isn't it defined as $X_0 : E(F_{p}) \rightarrow F_{p}$? ( or $X_0 : F_{p} \rightarrow F_{p}$ )

**Second Question**: When making a scalar multiplication on a point of a elliptic curve, the result is always a point. So why is it defined as $X_0 : E(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow F_{p^2}$ and not as $X_0 : E(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow E(F_{p^2})$? One can say, that $E(F_{p^2})$ is not the x-value of a point. In this case, why is it not defined as $X_0 : E(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow F_{p}$?

Comment: @kelalaka Sorry, i dont rly understand what you mean.

Comment: Functions are defined by: functions: input $\rightarrow$ output. When X is a reductions functions, that takes the result of a  already calculated scalar multiplication, then why is the output in $F_{p^2}$ and not in $F_p$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer now! Curve25519 does not have key validation. Usually you have a point $P =(x,y)$ on a elliptic curve $E$ over $F_p$. But there is not a point $P$ on the elliptic curve for every value in $F_p$. If you make a key exchange with such a system, you will get a point, or a x-Value (using Montgomery x-only computation). Now you have to test, wether the given point is on the elliptic curve or not, because you can't calculate with a point, thats not on the curve.

Now as i said Curve25519 does not have key validation, because it takes time. But the theorem (in which $X_0$ is defined, too) in the paper about Curve25519 that says, that there is a Point for every x-Value over $F_p$. So you don't need key validation!

The bottom line of is, that you only need the extension field $F_{p^2}$, because you don't want key validation.

Comment: You are right! I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

For your second question, if you're taking a point on $E(F_{p^2})$, both coordinates are elements of $F_{p^2}$. If you define a function $X':E(F_{p^2})\rightarrow F_p$, then it can't be extracting the x-value from the point.

If you look at the proof in appendix A, he needs to work in $F_{p^2}$ because he needs to be able to take the square root of any element.

Comment: But isn't the last parameter of a function the result set? E.g. $X': (x,y) \in E \rightarrow x$ and $x \in F_p$ because X(x,y) = x. So $X: E(F_{p^2}) \rightarrow F_p$ should be enough, because the function is only for extracting the x-value?

Comment: @Titanlord, I'm saying that if $(x,y) \in E(F_{p^2})$, then, $x\in F_{p^2}$ and $y \in F_{p^2}$

Comment: Yes, because $F_p \in F_{p^2}$. I think, that $x,y\in F_p$ is correct, too. Are there any special cases, am i wrong or does Bernstein use $F_{p^2}$ because $F_p \in F_{p^2}$ and therefore it doen't matter?

Comment: Just a note, $F_p \not \in F_{p^2}$. You can think of  $F_p \subset F_{p^2}$, which is what Bernstein does.